# best way to create single engine sqlalchemy with Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I use Flask and sqlalchemy. I want to create the engine only once as the documentation says

> The typical usage of create_engine() is once per particular database
>   URL, held globally for the lifetime of a single application process.

My basic idea is to put the engine as a class variable like

```
class EngineUnique:
    engine=sqla.create_engine(f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}")
```

and then when I need the engine do

```
with EngineUnique.engine.connect() as connection:
```

**Is it a correct way to do or do I have to implement the Singleton pattern?**

Loïc